# Cannot insert the value NULL into column X, column X does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I'm new to SQL Server and I am getting this error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Occupied', table 'DBProjectHamlet.dbo.tblGrave'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated."

This is my code for the insert followed by the code to create the table

```
INSERT INTO tblGrave (GraveName)
SELECT Grave
FROM tblPlotsandOccupants


IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tblGrave' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo')
    DROP TABLE dbo.tblGrave;
    GO
CREATE TABLE tblGrave
(
GraveID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
GraveName VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
GraveTypeID INT NOT NULL,
PlotID INT NOT NULL,
Occupied BIT NOT NULL
)
```

I'm not trying to insert anything into column Occupied, I don't know why this is happening or how to fix it. I just want to insert values into tblGrave (GraveName). Any help would be great.

Comment: You know that `GraveTypeID`, `PlotID`, and `Occupied` cannot be null.  Why would you only insert `GraveName` into the table?????

Comment: I only have data for GraveName at the moment and I just tried to change those and still got the same error.

Comment: According to your definition, a grave must have a Plot and a Type.  So you can't insert without those info.  Occupied is easy, you can always assign to default value (eg: 0 or 1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly!  You *aren't* doing anything with `Occupied` and that is the problem.  The column is specified to be `NOT NULL` but has no default value.  You are not inserting a value, so it gets the default.  The default default is `NULL`, and that is not allowed.

One simple solution is:

```
INSERT INTO tblGrave (GraveName, Occupied)
    SELECT Grave, 0
    FROM tblPlotsandOccupants;
```

This fixes your immediate problem, but will then you will get an error on `PlotId`.

A more robust solution would add a default value for the `NOT NULL` columns and declare the rest to be nullable (the default).  Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tblGrave (
    GraveID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    GraveName VARCHAR(MAX),
    GraveTypeID,
    PlotID INT,
    Occupied BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked I've changed my table schemas

Answer (score 0):

When you created your table, you defined that column as "NOT NULL" rather than allowing it to be null.

You need to either allow "Occupied" to be null, set a default value, or define the value that you want upon inserting.

You can even set the value to be ' ' which is blank but isn't null.

EDIT

Note @Gordon's answer for sql examples.